# Umbraco Membership population limit?

Tags: asp.net, umbraco

Could Umbraco Membership handle say 1 million users?
The Member data wouldn't be managed in backend but just by users on their my account page
is this feasible using the default setup or would I need to create a custom setup?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically it should work, since it uses the asp.net membership provider, which runs on sql server which can scale almost without limits.

That said, with a million users you are going to need some serious hardware to run the sql server database. If I had to guess as your number of users increase and starts to approach very large numbers, umbraco will have the problem(bottleneck) before the membership provider does.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, theoretically you're only limited to SQL Server specs. See this URL for more information: 
http://our.umbraco.org/forum/core/general/11920-Maximum-number-of-content-nodes-for-Umbraco-45